# conflict tkz-euclide and nag?

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, tkz-collection

Am I doing something wrong and is this meant to happen?

```
%\documentclass{minimal} edit: should not be used
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}
\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
     \tkzInit[xmin=-9, xmax=6, ymin=-0.7, ymax=5]
     \tkzDefPoint(0,0){x}
     \tkzDrawPoints(x)
     \tkzLabelPoints[below](x)
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

If I try to compile this (with pdflatex or xelatex) I get the following error

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line xx.
<inserted text> 
                \fi
```

If I leave off the `\begin{center}` and corresponding `\end{center}` the error message changes to:

```
Runaway argument?
\@xa \looseends \@xa :\@xa =\nag@envstack \do {\@xa \ifx \looseends \relax \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@tfor.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

1. Could someone explain this error message to me.
2. If I comment out either `\RequirePackage[..]{nag}` or `\tkzInit[..]` the error vanishes.

Comment: Not that this answers your question, but you should not use the `minimal` document class. See [Why not use the minimal class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-not-use-the-minimal-class).

Comment: Also `\Requirepackage` should be `\usepackage` and you might  prefer `\centering`.

Comment: On a completely unrelated topic, @epsilon. Are you sure that you want to use `U+2CC6 COPTIC CAPITAL LETTER OLD COPTIC ESH` in your user name, rather than `U+2215 DIVISION SLASH`?

Comment: I think you're not allowed to use non letter symbols in names - so division slash is no option - but I am not really happy with it - and have to wait till july 22nd to change my name back to epsilonhalbe

Comment: The correct tag is `tkz-euclide`. I gave an answer to this problem in another question but I can't relocate it. You can download the new file here :  http://altermundus.com/SandBox/tkz-tools-base.tex

Comment: @Altermundus thanks for providing this and many thanks for the `tkz-collection` you made it is really really helpful.

Comment: @epsilon'εⳆ2'halbe Thanks, happy that this work helps you. The real tag is `tkz-collection`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a name conflict between `nag.sty` and `tkz-tools-base.tex` (which is input via `tkz-euclide.sty`).

From `nag.sty`:

```
\let\@xa\expandafter
```

From `tkz-tools-base.tex`:

```
\global\let\@xa\tkz@init@xmin
```

Without one (or both) of the two package authors resolving the conflict by renaming things, I don't think you use the two packages together.

Comment: Yes you are right. This problem disappears with the new file tkz-tools-base.tex but I need times before to upload anew version on CTAN because I have some littles corrections to add.